# JavaScript and Html code to run all types of videos and gets there states

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can any one help me out to create JavaScript with html to run videos of all types and format including You tube, flash, Instagram, VUClip.

I also want to know current state of video like - buffering, start, stop, pause, completed, repeating etc.

I have tried with ,  etc.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried, would you like me to do the rest of your work for you also?

Comment: I feel you're on wrong site, you should put your requirements on  http://www.GetACoder.com

Comment: We might need a bit more of what you've done already, or you could make a pitch document, and we can make a bill for the end product. :D

Comment: I have tried with 

 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 

and 

 <video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video> 

but its not supporting all format like you tube video  flash, Instagram, VUClip and I also need state of video in java script

Comment: Well it's a little more than just a video tag, do some research, make some progress then come back.  No one is going just do your work for you. That is not how this community works.

Comment: well `flash` will be the best bet for you.

Comment: @Jai flash is not supported in IOS

Answer (score -1):

Try some existing solutions, for example [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) it's very useful and will allow you to achieve your goals, I hope.

Comment: thanks is it supportive for IOS, Android, ipad and other devices as well?

Comment: This is not an answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: @AnupamSharma, yes it supports IOS, as well as Android, Windows Phone and a lot of other platforms.

Comment: @MokshShah, sorry, I thought that it's useful and enough information to be an answer.